# Verb at the start of a clause

Tags: clauses

Can someone explain the grammar behind the 'came' used in the below sentence?

> With the sharp increase in consumer demand, **came** the drastic spike in orders.

Comment: The comma shouldn't be there. Other than that, your text is just an example of the stylistic choice of "fronting" an adverbial clause, which would more naturally be expressed in English in the sequence Subject+Verb+Adverb: *The drastic spike in orders came with the sharp increase in consumer demand*. Note that it would also be more natural to use the *indefinite* article *(**a**)* before ***drastic spike in orders***. But again, that's a stylistic choice, not a matter of whether something is grammatically valid.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This seems quite substantial; just curious why it's a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: @AndyBonner That's just how FF rolls

Comment: It usually takes me a *lot* longer just to format the same comment text into an actual Answer - not to mention which I'm usually just "shooting from the hip" with my comments anyway, but I usually do a least *some* confirmatory research before posting an Answer. But anyone else is welcome to transfer text from my comments to Answers (with or without attribution), if they believe it's both correct and helpful.